# Bash date comparison

Tags: bash, date, comparison

I'm trying to make a script that uses automatically generated date and also a hard limit for the date that is the lowest it can be.

So the script would be something like

```
DATE_USE=`date -v -3w +2018-%m-%d`
DATE_LIMIT=`date +2018-05-01`
//here something that if $DATE_USE < $DATE LIMIT -> DATE_USE=$DATE_LIMIT
```

But after searching for anwsers for this for a while I haven't really found anything that seems to help. Doing this on MAC OS and it should work also on Linux.

Comment: There is no `-v` on Linux. `date -d -3weeks +2018-%m-%d` should work. Then compare using `+%s` and the `-lt` numeric comparison.

Comment: Can I have a concrete example? Been trying to use the +%s for a while now when trying to get some date in seconds but it always gives me the current date in seconds or complains about the format.

Comment: Sure, in the first case, just use `date -d -3weeks +%s`, then in the second, use `date -d "2018-05-01" +%s` and finally compare with `if [ "$DATE_USE" -lt "$DATE_LIMIT" ]; then DATE_USE=$DATE_LIMIT; fi` Remember with `-d` you are telling `date` to use what follows as the date. In your case either 3-weeks ago or May 1.

Comment: Stillnot working, complains about the format. Am I writing the date wrong somehow? DATE=`date -d -3weeks +%s`

Comment: You should use *command substitution* either backticks (disfavored) or `DATE_USE=$(date -d "-3weeks" +%s)`. (also - it is preferable to quote the date string behind `-d`), e.g. `date -d "-3weeks"` outputs `Mon Apr 30 02:00:20 CDT 2018` and `date -d "-3weeks" +%s` outputs `1525071725`. (the number of seconds since `Jan 1, 1970` or *epoch* in other words)

Comment: Complains about format.   date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]

Comment: Ahh -- we have hit one of those MacOS v/Linux differences in a shell function. As I explained above, Linux has no `-v` and apparently MacOS is using `-v` instead of `-d` (which it apparently uses for daylight savings). So replace my `-d` with your `-v` and try again -- let me know so I know what Mac does. (I'm Macless or I would test)

Comment: Okay I figured out a way to not use the if-statement but I now can't get the wanted date with subtraction. So if I want to use some date -x months (e.g. 2018-04-01 minus 3 months or if I wanted to use that for the first day of this current month), how do I do that? (Now using Linux)

Comment: update to previous: no problem anymore. Just used date -d "-3 month" +%Y+%m-01

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin It doesn't really have anything to do with the shell; `date` is an external command whose POSIX specification is quite minimal, and macOS uses the BSD implementation of `date` rather than the GNU implementation, both of which have quite a few non-standard extensions.

Answer (score 0):

do the test in YYYYMMDD  format where the dates can be treated as integers.

```
lower_limit=`date -d "-3w" '+%y%m%d'`

DATE_USE=`date -d -3w +2018%m%d`
DATE_LIMIT=`date +20180501`


[ "$DATE_USE" -lt "$DATE_LIMIT" ] && DATE_USE=DATE_LIMIT

DATE_USE=`date -d "$DATE_USE" '+%y-%m-%d'`
```